# Highlight Date on calender with javascript according to the date on the PC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a calendar to work, I am trying to make the day it is on the computer highlighted in the site I have tried multiple things, but I can't get it to work, I know its gonna involve some Javascript or Jquery. but if it is possible, then without any plugins. I have a code, but I don't think it is gonna help that much in this situation...

EDIT:

Whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/gacwvtjx/
NEW code:http://jsfiddle.net/gacwvtjx/5/

I've already tried:

```
var date = new Date(),
year = date.getFullYear(),
month = date.getMonth(),
day = date.getUTCDate(),
months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
document.getElementById('day').classList.add("active");
document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = months[month];
document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = year;
```

it didn't exactly work as supposed, because I have the same id on many of my divs to make it work as I thought, but it didn't work anyhow.

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){

    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $parent.find('li').removeClass('current');
    $parent.parent().find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $parent.parent().find("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
var $parent = $(this).parent();

var date_id = $(this).attr('data-day');
    const CURRENT_DAY = (new Date).getDate()
$parent.parent().find("#"+date_id+CURRENT_DAY).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You need to add more information. What Jquery plugin are you using for dates? (most of them already do that), And try clarifying the question: Do you want the current time of the computer to highlight the date on your calendar or your website?

Comment: I am at the minute not using any plugins... I want it like today is the 10th, then I need to get the 10th on the calendar to highlight in red.

Comment: It would be usefull to see some of your code if you built a calendar from scratch. But that being said, just create a `new Date()` and using the date methods https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp figure out the day of the current date, and highlight the particular div that contains that particular day.

Comment: I have tried looking into that, but my problem is that i dont know how to let it highlight the day by itself. if i try to use `Addclassname` or something like that, it needs to know were to add the class, and in that case it need to confirm were it actually need to set it.

Comment: Aha, i assumed you created a grid out `<div>` or out of tabled `<td>` and each div, or TD filled will have an identifier like `data-day="10"` , and based on your current day you use jquery to find the specific `data-day` attribute that equals to the current day. or something along the lines of that.

Comment: i edited my post and added the code...

Comment: One thing i noticed is wrong, is that you have `id="day"` on all days. ID's should be unique. Second thing, you just have to add a unique identifier for each day, like `<li id="day1">1</li>` and then using something along the line of this: `$parent.parent().find("#day"+ CURRENT_DAY ).addClass('current');`.

Comment: what do i write in current_day?

Comment: CURRENT_DAY is a variable representing the current day. `const CURRENT_DAY = (new Date).getDate()` for example today is 10th of oct, this will return `10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Date()
```

returns you the current local date. Is this what you need?

I also supplied an example of generating calendar with current day highlighted.

If you need to highlight the date on already rendered calendar, you can use a combination of `querySelector` or `childNodes` to retrive the right element to highlight based on local date. But I have no idea how your calendar's HTML is built, so I can't tell more precisely.

```js
const now = new Date;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  generateCalendar(new Date());
});


function generateCalendar(date)
{
  const monthStartsAt = date.getDay() - (date.getDate()-1) % 7;
  const dayCount = getDaysInMonth(date.getYear(), date.getMonth());
  const emptyStart = (monthStartsAt + 6) % 7;
  const weeks = Math.ceil((emptyStart + dayCount) / 7);
  
  const calendar = document.querySelector(".calendar");
  
  let day = 1;
  
  for(var w = 0; w < weeks; w++)
  {
    const wElem = document.createElement("div");
    wElem.classList.add("week");
    
    if(w == 0)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < emptyStart; i++)
      {
        const dElem = document.createElement("div");
        dElem.classList.add("day");
        dElem.classList.add("empty");
        wElem.appendChild(dElem);
      }
    }
      
    do
    {
      const dElem = document.createElement("div");
      dElem.classList.add("day");
      
      if(date.getDate() == day)
        dElem.classList.add("today");
      
      dElem.innerHTML = day;
      wElem.appendChild(dElem);
      day++;
    }
    while((day + emptyStart) % 7 != 1 && day <= dayCount);
    
    calendar.appendChild(wElem);
  }
}

function getDaysInMonth(year, month)
{
  return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
}
```

```css
.calendar .week
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  width: 210px;
  display: flex;
}

.calendar .day
{
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

.calendar .day.today
{
  background-color: rgb(40, 200, 40);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="calendar">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can look at my code that i've added in my post. i have the dates written down but maybe i could change it with the way this is. what now if i want to see a month forward or backwars?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have several problems in your code:

- You have hardcoded the entire calendar. This is definitely wrong, after the end of the year it will not work properly. See the code in my current answer - it generates the calendar divs from code. The function I put there accepts date and generates calendar for the month that the given date is in. Switching month would be just clearing the .calendar div and calling the function again for the other month.
- All the labels have the ID "day". IDs should be unique, so what you did is illegal and will not work properly. The IDs could be "date_2018-10-10", and then you just format your date properly and form the ID from it.

**Warning**: Keep in mind, that Javascript counts months and weekdays from 0. Therefore month 0 is January, month 11 is December, weekday 0 is sunday and weekday 6 is Saturday.

Comment: so if i use your code, what should i do if i want to see the calender 2 months in the future and past?

Comment: and if im using your code, i cant write things like a real calender, because it will just erase it. like if i want to write what homework i have

Comment: So you probably need to modify my code somehow, I will definitely not solve all the problems for you.

You can add an argument to my function determining the id of div to generate calendar in and call the function multiple times to generate calendar in multiple divs.